# Does Flink has a "distribute by" command (similar to spark)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I want to shuffle the data by key and write the data to sink.

I'm not use group by because of it is no need for me do any aggregate.

So I wonder whether flink sql has keyword like "distribute by" in spark.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like a hack to me, but you could accomplish this with MATCH_RECOGNIZE and PARTITION BY. Hopefully there's a cleaner way that I'm not seeing.